# RubyGems - my system can't seem to find any remote gems to install

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, osx-tiger

Trying to install the 'less' gem.  I type `sudo gem install less` as instructed at http://lesscss.org/, and I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    Could not find less (> 0) in any repository
```

Alright, so I figure maybe I just need to update RubyGems.  Trying 'gem update --system' gets me

```
Updating RubyGems...
Attempting remote update of rubygems-update
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    rubygems-update requires builder >= 0
```

Arrgh.  Alright, then let's try 'sudo gem install builder':

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    Could not find builder (> 0) in any repository
```

Seems that no matter what gem I try to install, it can't be found in any repository.  I check my environment, and rubyforge is listed:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - VERSION: 0.9.4 (0.9.4)
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM PATH:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org
```

Any idea what's going on?   I'm on OSX 10.4, and I installed Ruby 1.8.6 before this.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* rubygems 1.3.x requires ruby 1.8.7 so you might install that first. Then update rubygems to 1.3.7. via `gem update --system`

Answer (score 0):

The version of rubygems bundled in osx uses gemforge as its offical source of gems - this has since been replaced with gemcutter.  You should be able to do

```
sudo gem update --system
```

To upgrade to update the latest version of ruby gems, which will then use gemcutter as the sources link

Answer (score 0):

That's a really old version of rubygems! How did you install this?

Is it a manual install? If so, perhaps you could try a [manual upgrade](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3) the same way.

Answer (score -1):

Do the following:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

to update your install of RubyGems.  Then, add the Github gem repository to your sources.  I suggest github because you'll find a lot of useful things there:

```
sudo gem sources -a http://gems.github.com
```

Comment: github has stated that their gem hosting will end at the end of this year, so I wouldn't count on that forever. presently gemcutter.org/rubygems.org is the official repo of gems.